Why doesn't Car-Parrinello molecular dynamics require an SCF calculation?
Reading the various terms of the Lagrangian in Car–Parrinello molecular dynamics, I'm trying to understand why there is not an SCF procedure hidden there.
In fact, it seems to me like the second term of the Euler-Lagrange equation is similar (except for the variational minimization) to that of Born-Oppenheimer molecular dynamics, also if it is placed equal to the "force" due to the fictitious mass.
I'm missing this essential and maybe obvious feature to appreciate this method.
I'm sorry for not writing the equations.

Crossposted to Matter Modeling and Chemistry SE. Please note that generally it is discouraged to do so. Please also link there to both other posts to the other sides, respectively.

It is not entirely true that Car-Parrinello (CP) Molecular Dynamics (MD) doesn't require a self-consistent field  (SCF) calculation at all. The method must start close to the SCF solution (actually a minimum) for the electronic degrees of freedom corresponding to the initial ionic positions. The main difference with the so-called Born-Oppenheimer (BO) Molecular Dynamics is that a new SCF calculation (minimization) is required at each time step in the BO case. Instead, in the CP MD, the special fictitious dynamics of the Kohn-Sham wavefunctions ensures that the electronic energy remains close to the BO energy surface without additional minimization steps. Then, the forces on the ions are very close to the BO case.
To make this answer understandable to a broader audience, I'll briefly explain BO and CP MD, focusing on the physical principles at the basis of CP MD. Therefore, I won't write the functional forms explicitly and ignore additional details like the orthonormalization constraints on wavefunctions.
The original problem Car and Parrinello wanted to solve was how to implement a classical Molecular Dynamics numerical simulation (i.e. a numerical integration of the classical Newtonian equations of motion) with the forces on the ions obtained by adding the ion-ion Coulomb interactions and the electrostatic force on the ions due to the electronic density calculated with a status-of-the-art quantum method (Density Functional Theory (DFT), in the Kohn and Sham formalism).
DFT obtains the electronic density from a minimization problem of a suitable functional. The challenge for an MD technique is that such minimization should be performed at each step so that the electronic degrees of freedom can adjust for ionic movement. Due to the many degrees of freedom required for a good description of the electronic components (hundreds of thousands or more), a complete minimization at each time step is a heavy computational burden.
The essence of the problem Car and Parrinello managed to solve can be described in a general form as follows:
We have an energy potential surface for the set of dynamical variables $\{X_I\}$ obtained  from
$$
E(\{X_I\}) = min_{\{x_{\alpha}\}} \tilde E(\{X_I\},\{x_{\alpha}\} ),
$$
where $\tilde E$ depends on the $\{X_I\}$ and on the $\{x_{\alpha}\} $.
The BO dynamics corresponds to a set of dynamic equations.
$$
M_K \ddot X_K = -\nabla_{X_K} E(\{X_I\}).\tag{1}
$$
The $\{X_I\}$ will evolve at each time step in numerical integration. Therefore, at each time step, the re-evaluation of $E(\{X_I\})$ requires a new minimization of $\tilde E$ over the slave degrees of freedom $\{x_{\alpha}\} $. Such minimization of a function of many degrees of freedom is time-consuming and must be performed with very high accuracy.
The idea behind the CP method is to perform such minimization only at the initial time. Then, in addition to the dynamics of the $\{X_I\}$'s, a concurrent dynamics of the $\{x_{\alpha}\} $'s is introduced. The idea is that if $\tilde E$ is at a minimum with respect to the $\{x_{\alpha}\} $'s, at the initial values of $\{X_I\}$'s, as soon as they change, the system won't be at the equilibrium configuration, but at a slightly perturbed point not too far from the new instantaneous minimum. Since the fake dynamics of the $\{x_{\alpha}\} $'s is arbitrary, we can introduce another Newton-like set of equations of motions
$$
\begin{align}
M_K \ddot X_K = -\nabla_{X_K} \tilde E(\{X_I\}, \{x_{\alpha}\})\\
m_{\lambda} \ddot x_{\lambda} = -\nabla_{x_{\lambda}} \tilde E(\{X_I\},\{x_{\alpha}\}).\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
In general, the resulting motion will be a combined evolution of both $\{X_I\}, \{x_{\alpha}\}$, where, at least initially, the $ \{x_{\alpha}\}$
oscillate around the evolving minimum of $ \tilde E(\{X_I\},\{x_{\alpha}\})$.
However, we can use values of the fake masses $m_{\lambda}$ so small that the oscillations of $ \{x_{\alpha}\}$ are fast, and the typical frequencies of these degrees of freedom are significantly higher than the frequencies of the  $\{X_I\}$'s.
Under such conditions, and assuming that the minimum with respect to $\{x_{\alpha}\}$ remains structurally stable, Classical Mechanics ensures that

the oscillations around the instantaneous minimum of the $ \{x_{\alpha}\}$ will remain small (the transfer of energy between variables varying on different time scales is highly ineffective;
the average evolution of the $ \{x_{\alpha}\}$ is such that the system remains significantly close to the instantaneous minimum with respect to the $ \{x_{\alpha}\}$'s for very long times.

That's the core of the CP MD and why it doesn't require a new complete minimization at each time step.
Of course, there are cases where the method does not work. In particular when a significant lowering of the frequencies of the $ \{x_{\alpha}\}$'s are expected.

Edit to clarify the special role of the Newton-like dynamics for the electronic degrees of freedom
Notice that the core of the CP method is in introducing fast Newton-like dynamics for the variables $x_{\alpha}$. One could ask why not use the more obvious dynamics provided by the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for the electronic wavefunctions.
Indeed, it would be possible to do it. However, it turns out that the instantaneous spectrum of oscillations of the electronic degrees of freedom resulting from equation ($2$) is much more convenient than the one resulting from the so-called Ehrenfest dynamics
$$
\begin{align}
M_K \ddot X_K = -\nabla_{X_K} \tilde E(\{X_I\}, \{x_{\alpha}\})\\
i \mu_{\lambda} \dot x_{\lambda} = -\nabla_{x_{\lambda}} \tilde E(\{X_I\},\{x_{\alpha}\}).\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Here $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $\mu_{\lambda}$ are adjustable parameters that can be used to optimize the method.
In the usual application of the method, a single parameter is introduced ( $m_{\lambda}=m$ or $\mu_{\lambda}=\mu$ ). In such a case, it can be shown that the Newton-like dynamics of equation ($2$) results in a more efficient numerical method. Indeed, let's fix the parameters $m$ and $\mu$ to ensure the same separation between electronic and ionic frequencies (i.e., the same quality of the adiabatic decoupling necessary to keep the electronic variables close to the instantaneous ground state). The difference between the two dynamics is that the width of the spectrum of the fast oscillations is smaller with the Newton-like dynamics than with the Ehrenfest-like. Therefore, the highest frequency of the fast variable motion is smaller, allowing a larger time step than in the case of the dynamics controlled by the equations ($3$).

Many thanks! I'm new in this field, so some things are not obvious. Why if the minimization is only at the initial step you must introduce an equation of motion?                                                 Another important thing: in CPMD how do you solve the orbitals equation of motion if not in SCF way?

@Chemistry. Once the ions move, according to the forces evaluated at the initial configuration, the electronic configuration no longer corresponds to the minimum of the electronic Hamiltonian in the presence of the ions. Therefore, the electronic degrees of freedom need to be updated. This could be done with a new SCF calculation (BO MD) or, cleverly, by introducing independent Netwon-like dynamics for them. The intriguing part of the CP method is that such dynamics does not need an explicit minimization (SCF calculation) at each time step. It is the oscillatory dynamics...

@Chemistry. ... of the electronic degrees of freedom that takes care to keep the system very close to the instantaneous minimum. In a way, CP dynamics restores at a classical Newton-like level, the quantum adiabatic evolution of the electrons.

The first question now is very clear, thanks! But what kind of equation, in a mathematical sense, is the equation of motion of the electrons? If I look at this equation why I can say it's more convenient than the Schrodinger's one? Why we talk about an oscillatory dynamics of the orbitals?

@Chemistry. Newton-like equations of motion. However, since the starting condition for the electronic degrees of freedom is very close to the minimum of the total potential energy, if such a minimum is not too shallow and if not too much energy is transferred from the ionic to the electronic motion, the electronic dynamics may continue oscillating around the evolving minimum for very long times.

@Chemistry. Usually, I refrain from self-citation, but in this case, I think you may find it useful to have a look at a quite old paper of mine: https://www.aquila.infn.it/cpierleo/MCMC/AIMD/BIBLIO/pastoresmargiassibuda.pdf

Great! This paper might be useful for my situation, thanks! Now I try also to take advantage of your willingness to explain in this moment... the minimum of energy evolves due to the nuclear dynamics, is right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Great answer! (+1) Btw you mentioned that the electrons move using Newton-like equations of motion. Could you elaborate why the electrons cloud cannot simply be time-evolved directly, please? The ions are simulated classically, and their respective location gives off the potential V at each moment, so the complete potential landscape is known at any time, then shouldn't $\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$ directly reveal the next whereabouts of the electrons cloud?

@James, I'll add a paragraph about this point.
